# Is the Nocturnus song "Subterranean Infiltrator" about Metal Gear, or is it actually set in its universe?

Tags: inspiration, metal-gear-solid, nocturnus

*Thresholds*, the 1992 sophomore release by the progressive death metal band [Nocturnus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnus), contains a song "Subterranean Infiltrator", which Wikipedia claims [is about the *Metal Gear* video game series](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Thresholds_(album)&oldid=1002595450).

Listening to the song and reading [its lyrics](http://www.darklyrics.com/lyrics/nocturnus/thresholds.html#6), and having only superficial knowledge of the *Metal Gear* franchise, I wondered if the song is actually set *in* the *Metal Gear* universe, as a sort of musical fan fiction, or if it's merely *about* the game (and set in our own universe), more or less describing the experience of playing the game.

> Moving quickly
> Towards goal
> Stealth the key
> Clear path
> To achieve lethal detonation
>
> Flares of weapons
> Burst in synch
> Give way
> Delay charge
> Chemical timers are now set
>
> Once on the surface
> Reconnaissance picks him up
> On the scope
> Subterranean specialist
> Looks down below
> As the mountain lies in rubble
>
> *<sub>"Subterranean Infiltrator" by Nocturnus, final verses</sub>*

**Is the Nocturnus song "Subterranean Infiltrator" merely *about* (playing) *Metal Gear*, or is it actually set in its universe?**

Comment: Goddamn it, I wrote up an entire answer about how it was kinda similar to MGS3 before noticing the song was released in 1992. Note for others - if it is referencing Metal Gear, it's about the original 1987 game!

Comment: @DavidS I've added the year of release; I'm sorry I hadn't done so already. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Not your fault, I should have noticed :P

Comment: Why not [ask him](https://www.facebook.com/MikeBrowning666)?

Comment: @Valorum I'd need to be on _Facebook_ for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked [Mike Browning](https://www.facebook.com/MikeBrowning666) on Facebook (props to Valorum for the link) in private messages (sorry for that). Looks like the lyrics weren't *explicitly* inspired by *Metal Gear* series: Mike Browning didn't write that song, but he never heard anyone even mention the games while the song was written.

Here are his responses in their entirety (all emphasis mine):

> Actually **I didn't write the lyrics to this particular song**, I do know it was more about a military guy who sneaks into an enemy camp. I don't remember anyone in the band ever talking about Metal Gear the game, so I don't think that it had any influence on the lyrics.
>
> I am not really sure when Metal Gear actually came out, but I remember Davis and Lou talking about what they were writing about when we were working on the song and **it was about an army guy sneaking into the enemy army base**. Not my kind of lyrics that I would ever write, but on Thresholds several of the band members wrote lyrics and came up with the ideas for them, not like on "The Key" where it was mostly me and Davis.
>
> **I never heard anyone in the band talk about Metal Gear ever and I was there when the song was being written, so it definitely wasn't based on Metal Gear.** If anything it would have came from Davis watching old GI Joe cartoons, he was into that and Transformers.